# Keycloak give read time out error while calling external IDP APIs

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect, keycloak-services

I am using `keycloak 11.0.2` as identity broker and I have added couple of identity providers with `OpenID Connect V1`.

When user try to login in one Identity provider, user is getting unexpected error in UI and this behaviour is not observed all the time(1/10).
While checking keycloak logs, I see there is timeout in userinfo endpoint.

logs:

```
2022-01-20T08:32:53.013077386Z stdout F Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    
    ......
    
org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.12.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
2022-01-20T08:32:53.012493482Z stdout F     at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.12.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:393)
2022-01-20T08:32:53.012485382Z stdout F     at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.12.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:432)
2022-01-20T08:32:53.012477382Z stdout F     at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.12.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:543)
2022-01-20T08:32:53.012467282Z stdout F     at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.12.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
2022-01-20T08:32:53.012456182Z stdout F     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
2022-01-20T08:32:53.012432882Z stdout F     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2022-01-20T08:32:53.011913079Z stdout F     at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor568.invoke(Unknown Source)
2022-01-20T08:32:53.011900478Z stdout F     at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@11.0.2//org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider$Endpoint.authResponse(AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider.java:472)
2022-01-20T08:32:53.011880878Z stdout F     at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@11.0.2//org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.getFederatedIdentity(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:386)
2022-01-20T08:32:53.011803978Z stdout F 08:32:53,010 ERROR [org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (default task-21) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityBrokerException: Could not fetch attributes from userinfo endpoint.
```

My assumption is userinfo end point failed to respond in some specific time.Am I correct?

What is read time when keycloak make API call to IDP?

How can I change this timeout?

Here I am using Docker image to run keycloak with mariaDB.

Comment: Does your Keycloak container has network connectivity to that userinfo endpoint?

Comment: Yes, It has connectivity and it not consistent behaviour

Comment: Any update on this issue? Any solution?

Comment: @SANDEEPMACHIRAJU No, I am still not able to figure out how to change the timeout for IDP APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I used keycloak as a docker container, and I increased the socket timeout as shown below, and it worked for me:

```
 FROM jboss/keycloak:15.0.2
 ARG GIT_COMMIT_SHA=unspecified
 LABEL GIT_COMMIT_SHA=$GIT_COMMIT_SHA
 
 #Add socket timeout for outgoing http requests
 RUN sed -i -e '/^            <spi name="connectionsHttpClient">/!b;n;c\
             <provider name="default" enabled="true">\
                 <properties>\
                     <property name="connection-pool-size" value="256"/>\
                     <property name="socket-timeout-millis" value="120000"/>\
                 </properties>\
             </provider>' $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
RUN sed -i -e '/^            <spi name="connectionsHttpClient">/!b;n;c\
             <provider name="default" enabled="true">\
                 <properties>\
                     <property name="connection-pool-size" value="256"/>\
                     <property name="socket-timeout-millis" value="120000"/>\
                 </properties>\
             </provider>' $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml
```

**Note:** With the above changes, socket timeout is updated. But still, sometimes I see this problem. https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/13309 (FYI)

The above-mentioned spaces in the sed command are ad-hoc. Please suggest if anyone knows how to provide tab space in the sed command.